# Pandas Multi-Index Select Range on First Index?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a multi-level index dataframe with levels 0 and 1.  Level 0 is a date while level 1 is asset ids.

I'm simply trying to select a slice of the dataframe based on the level 0 index.  For example:

df[-10:] would retrieve all rows under the last 10 indices according to level 0.

I've tried a variety of things of similar nature to this:

```
master_df.loc[(-3, ), :]
```

Typically I end up with some form of type mismatch for the level.  The level 0 index is of a date time, but I have sorted it and want to access a numerical range.  My slice should contain the most recent X days with all associated assets and data within that.

Here is another failed attempt to get the 10 most recent with all second indexes and all columns.  It fails for "Can't do slice indexing on class DatetimeIndex with these indexers of class int"

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
master_df.loc[idx[-10:,:], :]
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

You can sort your index, then get back the values as an array and slice that and place it into a .loc slicer.  Below is a working example:

```
def get_slice(slicer, df):
    vals = df.index.levels[0][-slicer:]
    return df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[vals,:], :].copy()
```

This will slice the first index by n (starting at the end) giving you back concrete values in an array, which you can then feed into .loc which will take an array of values.